# Is there a way to scale c3.js graph if the data is small?

Tags: javascript, c3.js

I have data to display on c3.js graph and there is one piece of data which is smaller than other ones.

For exmaple A can by 140 000, B 20 000 and C 700. C can even be negative.
The problem is that when I display my data on the chart you can't really see the dynamics of C because its' values are too little for scale of the graph. If C is negative it doesn't show on the graph at all.

Is there some way to scale the graph that way so all data displayed properly?

```
const chartConfig = {
        bindto: $element.find('.canvas')[0],

        data: {
          json: [],
          keys: { value: [] },
          type: 'line'
        },

        grid: {
          x: {
            get: getXGrid
          }
        },

        axis: {
          y: { min: 0 },
          x: {
            tick: {
              culling: false,
              format: formatXAxis
            }
          },
          y2: {
            padding: {top: 0, bottom: 0},
            min    : 0,
            max    : 100,
            tick   : {
              format: (value) => `${value}%`
            }
          }
        }
      };
```

Later in one of my methods I set Y max to be the biggest number in data.

```
chartConfig.axis.y.max = getRoundMax(chartConfig.data);
```

UPD [link](https://jsfiddle.net/9b2drn50/)

Answer (score 0):

You must be looking for logarithmic scale.
At this moment c3.js does not support for it out-of-the-box.
But there are some [workarounds at github](https://github.com/c3js/c3/issues/252):

First, they convert values:

```
data_test_original = ['data1', 140000, 20000, 700, 10, 100, 1000, 3, 500, 50, 5, 3000]
data_test = ['data1'];
for(var i=1; i<data_test_original.length; i++){
    data_test[i] = Math.log(data_test_original[i]) / Math.LN10;
}
```

Then, they use it alongside with adjusted Y-axis:

```
c3.generate({
    data: {
        ...
        columns: [ data_test ]
    },
    ...
    axis : {
        y : {
            tick: {
               format: function (d) { return Math.pow(10,d).toFixed(0); }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

See full example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/86chryat/) or [there](https://jsfiddle.net/Dimmy/w5cjn7Lk/). Hope this will suit your needs.

Comment: Hmm tried it - for my axis `y` it says `infinity` and all my numbers have changed - for example 42019 turned into 4.623445712523772

Comment: Could you put your example code at jsfiddle or codepen? Also please compare versions of used libs.

Comment: Kind of tried to implement the structure of my data here https://jsfiddle.net/9b2drn50/

Comment: I'm sorry @Allan, this will not work for negative values as ```Math.log(-x)``` is ```NaN```.